# django migration error after adding new field

Tags: django

Previously i had models like this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PostJob(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    company  = models.ForeignKey('Company',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

later i added "desc" in PostJob model like this:

```
    class Company(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class PostJob(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
        desc  = models.TextField(default=None)
        company  = models.ForeignKey('Company',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

Then i ran below command :

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

when i am opening the "PostJob" in my django-admin panel it is showing below error.

```
MigrationError at /admin/api/postjob/
desc
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/api/postjob/
Django Version: 2.1.3
Exception Type: MigrationError
Exception Value:    
desc
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py in _align_results, line 290
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.7
Python Path:    
['/usr/src/rango_api',
 '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 18 Dec 2018 18:14:24 +0000
```

I thing the migrations are not affecting to my database.

Please have A look into my code

Comment: remove default=None

Comment: it won't work.  I tried

Comment: Are you sure you created migration for it? If you so, can you check which migrations applied by typing `python manage.py showmigrations`?